# Why do I need to include ClassLoader.getSystemResourcesAsStream() when parsing an xml file in java?

Tags: java, xml

So I'm learning how to parse an XML file in Java, and I begin with this:

```
public class XMLParser {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("yql.xml"));


    }
}
```

I'm unsure as to why I need to use ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("yql.xml"). I found this solution online because I could not just use builder.parse("yql.xml"). My question is: Why do I need to include this line when I'm reading an xml file? What does it do, and is there an easier way to read XML using the DOM without using ClassLoader?

Comment: `What does it do` Start by reading the javadoc.

Comment: You only need it if, the XML file is embedded within the application context or the resources is known to exist somewhere within the classpath context of the application...

Comment: Acceptance will be accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall read an XML as an `InputStream` to pass it to DOM parser.

The only point is where the XML file is, and according to each location you can use a different mechanism.

If you know the exact location of the XML file and you want to hard-code it in your application you can do something like:

```
InputSteram is = new FileInputStream("/path/to/xml/file.xml");
```

If you are storing your XML in your classpath (between your classes or in an JAR file which is included in class-path), you shall find it by a proper `ClassLoader`.

```
InputSream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("yql.xml");
```

If you are developing a WEB application and your XML is your WEB-INF folder, you shall use something like:

```
InputStream is = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/relative/path/to/xml/file.xml");
```

and so on (there could be other solutions, such as retrieving XML from an URL, reading from a ZIP file, and ...).

So using a `ClassLoader` is not a must, it totally depends on your project+XML file layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(String name)
```

is used to read a resource as a stream from the classpath. One advantage of using this is that it allows to avoid hard coding the path of your file. So when you use this statemet:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("yql.xml")
```

you are actually not giving the complete/relative path of your yql.xml. If your file is present in the classpath then it will be fetched.